# Pass a closure from Cython to C++

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a C++ function that accepts a callback, like this:

```
void func(std::function<void(A, B)> callback) { ... }
```

I want to call this function from Cython by giving it a closure, i.e. something I would have done with a lambda if I was calling it from C++. If this was a C function, it would have some extra `void*` arguments:

```
typedef void(*callback_t)(int, int, void*);

void func(callback_t callback, void *user_data) {
    callback(1, 2, user_data);
}
```

and then I would just pass `PyObject*` as `user_data` (there is a more detailed [example here](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Demos/callback)).

Is there way to do this more in C++ way, without having to resort to explicit `user_data`?

Comment: Googling `cython std function` gives an [example](https://github.com/hildensia/py_c_py) (not a library) that seems relevant.

Comment: @bereal Make your question self contained please (regarding the examples) as is, it's not very useful for future research.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ fair enough, will update once I'm back to keyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I believe you're aiming to do is pass a callable Python object to something accepting a `std::function`. You need to do create a bit of C++ code to make it happen, but it's reasonably straightforward.

Starting by defining "accepts_std_function.hpp" as simply as possible to provide an illustrative example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

inline void call_some_std_func(std::function<void(int,const std::string&)> callback) {
    callback(5,std::string("hello"));
}
```

The trick is then to create a wrapper class that holds a `PyObject*` and defines `operator()`. Defining `operator()` allows it to be converted to a `std::function`. Most of the class is just refcounting. "py_obj_wrapper.hpp":

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>
#include "call_obj.h" // cython helper file

class PyObjWrapper {
public:
    // constructors and destructors mostly do reference counting
    PyObjWrapper(PyObject* o): held(o) {
        Py_XINCREF(o);
    }
    
    PyObjWrapper(const PyObjWrapper& rhs): PyObjWrapper(rhs.held) { // C++11 onwards only
    }
    
    PyObjWrapper(PyObjWrapper&& rhs): held(rhs.held) {
        rhs.held = 0;
    }
    
    // need no-arg constructor to stack allocate in Cython
    PyObjWrapper(): PyObjWrapper(nullptr) {
    }
    
    ~PyObjWrapper() {
        Py_XDECREF(held);
    }
    
    PyObjWrapper& operator=(const PyObjWrapper& rhs) {
        PyObjWrapper tmp = rhs;
        return (*this = std::move(tmp));
    }
    
    PyObjWrapper& operator=(PyObjWrapper&& rhs) {
        std::swap(held, rhs.held);
        return *this;
    }
    
    void operator()(int a, const std::string& b) {
        if (held) { // nullptr check 
            call_obj(held,a,b); // note, no way of checking for errors until you return to Python
        }
    }
    
private:
    PyObject* held;
};
```

This file uses a very short Cython file to do the conversions from C++ types to Python types. "call_obj.pyx":

```
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef public void call_obj(obj, int a, const string& b):
    obj(a,b)
```

You then just need to create the Cython code wraps these types. Compile this module and call `test_func` to run this. ("simple_version.pyx":)

```
cdef extern from "py_obj_wrapper.hpp":
    cdef cppclass PyObjWrapper:
        PyObjWrapper()
        PyObjWrapper(object) # define a constructor that takes a Python object
             # note - doesn't match c++ signature - that's fine!
             
cdef extern from "accepts_std_func.hpp":
    void call_some_std_func(PyObjWrapper) except +
            # here I lie about the signature
            # because C++ does an automatic conversion to function pointer
            # for classes that define operator(), but Cython doesn't know that
            

def example(a,b):
    print(a,b)
    
def test_call():
    cdef PyObjWrapper f = PyObjWrapper(example)
    
    call_some_std_func(f)
```

---

The above version works but is somewhat limited in that if you want to do this with a different `std::function` specialization you need to rewrite some of it (and the conversion from C++ to Python types doesn't naturally lend itself to a template implementation). One easy way round this is to use the Boost Python library `object` class, which has a templated `operator()`. This comes at the cost of introducing an extra library dependency.

First defining the header "boost_wrapper.hpp" to simplify [the conversion from `PyObject*` to `boost::python::object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/object.html#tutorial.object.creating_python_object)

```
#include <boost/python/object.hpp>

inline boost::python::object get_as_bpo(PyObject* o) {
    return boost::python::object(boost::python::handle<>(boost::python::borrowed(o)));
}
```

You then just need to Cython code to wrap this class ("boost_version.pyx"). Again, call `test_func`

```
cdef extern from "boost_wrapper.hpp":
    cdef cppclass bpo "boost::python::object":
        # manually set name (it'll conflict with "object" otherwise
        bpo()
        
    bpo get_as_bpo(object)
    
    
cdef extern from "accepts_std_func.hpp":
    void call_some_std_func(bpo) except + # again, lie about signature

def example(a,b):
    print(a,b)
    
def test_call():
    cdef bpo f = get_as_bpo(example)
    
    call_some_std_func(f)
```

---

A "setup.py"

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension(
           "simple_version",                       # the extension name
           sources=["simple_version.pyx", "call_obj.pyx" ],
           language="c++",                        # generate and compile C++ code
      ),
    Extension(
           "boost_version",                       # the extension name
           sources=["boost_version.pyx"],
           libraries=['boost_python'],
           language="c++",                        # generate and compile C++ code
      )
    ]

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(extensions))
```

---

(A final option is to use `ctypes` to generate a C function pointer from a Python callable. See [Using function pointers to methods of classes without the gil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878942/using-function-pointers-to-methods-of-classes-without-the-gil/34900829#34900829) (bottom half of answer) and http://osdir.com/ml/python-cython-devel/2009-10/msg00202.html. I'm not going to go into detail about this here.)

Comment: Just great, especially thanks for the boost templated `operator()`. I actually already did something along the lines of what @user2357112 referred to, but having to rewrite the wrappers for each new callback signature was really annoying. That example was also missing the reference counting part. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Boost is obviously the way to go here (it's almost effort-free!). I wanted to show how you _could_ do it without boost, but I wouldn't actually use that code unless boost really isn't an option.

Comment: I think your implementation of `operator=(PyObjWrapper&&)` may be leaking memory, it's not calling Py_XDECREF

Comment: @AlicePurcell - it's the move assignment operator - it's transferring ownership from `rhs` to `this` so I think the total reference count should stay the same. It's possible I've made a mistake but I think it's right

Comment: I think you're forgetting that it's assignment, not construction, so `this` may already own something, and needs to free it.
Before: this holds A, rhs holds B.
After: this holds B, rhs holds nothing.
You need to free A

Comment: @AlicePurcell You're right - thanks