# How to wrap boost::function<> in Cython

Tags: c++, boost, cython

I have a C++ class with a boost::function<> as argument of a method:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void method(const boost::function<void(const T&)>& callback) {
        // do some stuffs
    }
};
```

I want to wrap this method which takes this boost::function<> as an argument in Cython, kindly suggest how can I achieve this.

C++ standard: 17

Comment: I don't think it matters much but is there a special reason why you use `boost::function` instead of `std::function`?

Comment: Not any specific reason, the code base mostly uses boost

Comment: I see. What errors do you get? Is the function template `private` as in your example?

Comment: This is a public method, and sorry for my mistyped code, I actually couldn't yet find the way to implement this, no compilation yet, seeking help

Comment: Did you find [Cython: std::function callbacks with custom parameter types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943940/cython-stdfunction-callbacks-with-custom-parameter-types) ? It seems to be pretty detailed.

Comment: I think the real question is "what would your perfect Python interface look like"? I.e. what do you actually want to do with this function? Whatever happens you'll have to constrain the template argument though.

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044063/pass-a-closure-from-cython-to-c might be useful though