# CYTHON, How can i pass a member function as a callback to native

Tags: python, callback, cython, stdbind, cythonize

I am able to get normal callbacks from native to Cython.

But, how do i set a member function to be callback in cython.

My `sampleCallback.h` file is :

```
 namespace mango {
 class sampleCalls { 
 public:
     typedef void (*Callback)(char *name);

     sampleCalls(Callback method, char *name);
     void execute();
 private:
     Callback _method;
     char *_key;
 }; }
```

And my `sampleCallback.cpp` file contains simple implementation :

```
 namespace mango {
        sampleCalls::sampleCalls(Callback method, char *name) {
                _method = method;
                _key = name;
        };
        void sampleCalls::execute()
        {
                return _method(_key);
        };
}
```

Now i have written a very simple cython wrapper `callback.pyx`:

```
ctypedef void (*Callback)(char *name)

cdef extern from "sampleCallback.h" namespace "mango" :
        cdef cppclass sampleCalls:
                sampleCalls(Callback method, char *name)
                void execute()

cdef void callbackCY(char* name):
        print "I AM ", name

cdef class pyCallback:
    cdef sampleCalls* sc

    def __init__(self):
            self.sc = new sampleCalls(callbackCY, "BATMAN")

    def  execute(self):
            self.sc.execute()
```

This builds and works fine when i run a simple python code :

```
import callback
cb = callback.pyCallback()
cb.execute()
```

This works just fine and outputs :: **I AM BATMAN**

But this is not what i want.
I want the callback function to be a part of the cython defined class,
so i implemented the class something like this :

```
cdef class pyCallback:
    cdef sampleCalls* sc

    def __init__(self):
        self.sc = new sampleCalls(cb, "BATMAN")

    def  execute(self):
        self.sc.execute()

    cdef void cb(self, char* name):
        print name, " WINS"
```

This does not work of course as callback prototype do not match.

WHAT IS THE PROPER WAY TO DO IT?

I also tried std::bind something like this ::

```
cdef place1 "std::placeholder1"
cdef bind_py "std::bind"

cdef class pyCallback:
    cdef sampleCalls* sc

    def __init__(self):
        self.sc = new sampleCalls(bind_py(self.cb, self, place1),     "BATMAN")
```

This does not work either.
The error ::

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef class pyCallback:
    cdef sampleCalls* sc

    def __init__(self):
            self.sc = new sampleCalls(bind_py(self.cb, self, place1), "BATMAN")
                                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

callback.pyx:19:40: Cannot convert 'void (pyCallback, char *)' to Python object

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef class pyCallback:
    cdef sampleCalls* sc

    def __init__(self):
            self.sc = new sampleCalls(bind_py(self.cb, self, place1), "BATMAN")
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

callback.pyx:19:35: Cannot convert Python object to 'Callback'
```

How can i get this done ?? Please help.

Comment: [See the second part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878942/using-function-pointers-to-methods-of-classes-without-the-gil/34900829#34900829) for an approach that uses Ctypes. If you can change the signature to a C++ `std::function` then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46204346/4657412)

Comment: Hello DavidW, I tried to implement as per the second part of your answer.

ftype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(c_void, POINTER(c_char))
f = ftype(self.internalCallback)

But am not sure what to do with the 3rd line 
"cdef someFunctionPointer cy_f_ptr = (<someFunctionPointer*><size_t>ctypes.addressof(f))[0]"
How do i declare this ? 
What should i replace "someFunctionPointer" with ?
It is supposed to be 'type identifier' right ?

Comment: "someFunctionPointer" is a `ctypedef` of a C function pointer. e.g. do `ctypedef void (*someFunctionPointer)(char*)` to make `someFunctionPointer` be a pointer to a function that accepts a char* and returns nothing.