# Cython has "first class function objects" - how efficient are they? Do they have Python overhead?

Tags: callback, cython

I have an external library that computes the optima, say minima, of a given function. Say its headers give me a function

```
double[] minimizer(ObjFun f)
```

where the headers define

```
typedef double (*ObjFun)(double x[])
```

I have generated Cython wrappers for this library. I now want to give user parameterized functions to it, specifically, I want to write a function

```
def getFunction(double q11, double q12, double q22):
    cdef f(double x[]):
        return x[0]*x[0]*q11 + 2*x[0]*x[1]*q12 +  x[1]*x[1]*q22
return f
```

that the user calls with their parameters (q11, q12, q22) to get a function that can be used as a callback for the C optimization library.

(The example above is contrived and simplified, the whole point of doing this in Cython is that I want nearly-C-efficient callbacks to give to the library.)

There is no way to do this in C, as observed by people in my other question. But in Cython I can compile this:

```
cdef class Quadratic:
    cdef double q11
    cdef double q12
    cdef double q22
    def __cinit__(self, double a, double b, double c):
        self.q11 = a
        self.q12 = b
        self.q22 = c
    cdef f(self, double x[]):
        return self.q11*x[0]*x[0] + self.q12*x[0]*x[1] + self.q22*x[1]*x[1]
```

(I have not yet tried using a generated function like this as an input to the library).

My question - is there Python overhead in this evaluation? I would like to have the parameterized function be nearly as efficient as if it were written in C.

If that is possible, how does Cython achieve this?

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem as you had: I want to generate an efficient callback to feed into a function minimiser. Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Unless this is a very new addition to Cython then) this *is not* valid Cython code and can't be made to work. It fails for me with the error

> C function definition not allowed here

The reason for this is that - as you already know - it is a genuine limitation of C: there is *no valid C code that Cython could generate to create a closure*. The reason being is that C would need to be able to dynamically generate a function at runtime to access the closured variables, and that isn't possible in standard C.

There are (at least) <s>two</s> three ways round this. First (and probably most sensible) you change your interface to accept a data pointer:

```
double[] minimizer(ObjFun f, void* data)
```

with

```
typedef double (*ObjFun)(double x[], void* data)
```

(where minimizer passes `data` to `f`.) If you're using an external library then you can't make this change, but I'd be surprised if it didn't use something like this - it's the standard solution.

The second way is to use `ctypes` to convert a Python callable into a C function pointer. This gets round the problem by dynamically generating machine code at runtime to match the C calling convention (and so can be blocked by security features that prohibit making memory executable). I show a basic example of how to do this in the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878942/using-function-pointers-to-methods-of-classes-without-the-gil/34900829#34900829). (I'm sure I have another more thorough answer showing this but I can't find it right now).

Using `ctypes` involves a reasonable amount of Python overhead, which is unavoidable.

*(Edited addition)* The third option to emulate a closure (somewhat unsatisfactorily) is to store the data in global variables:

```
# at global scope
q11 = 1.2
q22 = 3.2
q33 = 4.0

cdef double f(double x[]):
    # as before
```

The big limitation is that you can only use one version of `f` at once, so you can't run things in parallel or anything like that, but given the constraints that might be acceptable.

---

With respect to your cdef class version: calling it is pretty efficient *but* it effectively has a signature of:

```
`double (*)(Quadratic*, double [])`
```

so it won't fit the interface defined by your `minimizer` function.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question with Cython code that I have now seen compile. Can you comment on the validity/efficiency of that now?

Comment: See edit. It won't work I'm afraid. I've added a possible alternative solution that might be acceptable though (although not really a closure)

Comment: i am trying to find a way to change a Python function that i am submitting to the external C library to a C-efficient function and want to do this with the least code refactoring as possible. Hence all this thinking.

Comment: One final suggestion that I think might work pretty well: [try numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/cfunc.html). It generates code at runtime so should be able to make closures that work. I've never used it myself though, so if you have issues with it ask a new question rather than asking me!

Comment: Thanks. I think your global solution might work - I could try creating a function that modifies the global variables. I will try it out.

Comment: I am so sorry for pestering, but one more question: any comments on the efficiency of the ctypes route? If the callback needs to be evaluated many times (say in a search routine in an optimization function) do we basically incur all the Python overhead each time, right?

Comment: Yes. ctypes will have quite a bit of Python overhead on each call so is unlikely to be good for a function that is called lots of times.