# How to pass a python function to a cython function that accepts a function as a parameter?

Tags: python, cython

**I am rephrasing my original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619438/how-to-call-a-cython-cdef-function-that-contains-as-a-parameter-a-function-in) based on some of the comments (I recognized that when posted the question was not as precise as it could have been) in the hopes to find a answer.**

I have the following **cdef** function that among various other parameters accepts an **f()** function defined as an *ftype* as shown below,

```
%%cython
ctypedef double (*ftype) (double)

cdef cy_myfunc(int a,..., double x, ftype f):
  ...
  cdef double result
  result = f(x)
  return result
```

and I define a python function such as this:

```
def py_myfunc(a,..., x, f):
    return cy_myfunc(a,...,x,f)
```

I want to be able to call **py_myfunc()** and pass a user python function as the f parameter (the only prerequisite of the python function is that is should accept a double and return double). Is this possible? if so how can this be achieved in cython? The **f()** function is used repeatedly within a loop so I would like for it to be as quick as possible.

Comment: The last sentence of your question suggests you are hoping that by using your Cython typedef but then passing a Python function as `f`, you will somehow get a speedup of the pure-Python code in `f`.  That isn't going to work.  If a user writes a Python function and passes it to your `cy_fmyfunc`, Cython isn't going to speed it up just because you're calling it from within a `cdef`.  As suggested by deets below, you're probably better off not trying to specify any C-level type for `f`.

Comment: And why the solution/link proposed in this comment to your original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619438/how-to-call-a-cython-cdef-function-that-contains-as-a-parameter-a-function-in#comment94105070_53619438 doesn’t solve your problem?

Comment: Basically you need jit compilation of some boilerplate code for this to work - that is what ctypes is able to do for you.

Comment: @ead ctypes has nothing to do with that. It does not JIT anything. Mostly PyPy does. And some more arcane things in the scientific computing world.

Comment: @deets ctypes can generate a small "JIT" function around a Python callable, which allows you to translate that callable into a C function pointer. That's impossible to do without runtime code generation.

Comment: @marcos [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42887656/4657412) gives you a couple of other options if you're prepared to change the signature... Either way it'd be good to know why the link I gave on your other question isn't suitable

Comment: @DavidW I find this a stretch of the term JIT. But I understand what you mean. However within this context here, this is still not helping, as all it does is moving the PyObject_Call-Semantics just one step further away. It's then not cython generating that boilerplate, it's ctypes with cython immediately delegating to it.

Comment: @deets It isn't elegant or quick (or pure Cython), but it does solve the problem of turning a Python callable into a C function pointer. If the C interface is fixed then it's the only viable solution I know. If OP is able to change the C interface (e.g. to accept a PyObject* arguement) then I agree that there are better options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tinkered with cython in a while. But conceptually your approach is flawed. By hard-coding a C-type function that can ever only be a simple pointer-value, you limited yourself too much. A python function can never be that. It will ALWAYS be represented by a Py_Object, as any callable.

Just *don't* declare f as a ftype, but instead a normal python object (or no type at all), and then just call it. You need the full semantics of a passed Py_Object* anyways, as cython has no way to guarantee that the passed function is not completely different callable.