# Access class/instance attribute from C function in Cython

Tags: callback, attributes, global-variables, cython

I am working with a c library that uses `setCallback` functions. These functions take a function with a fixed signature, e.g.:

```
int glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_move);
```

Where `mouse_move` has signature

```
void mouse_move(GLFWwindow * window, double xpos, double ypos)
```

But suppose `mouse_move` depends on other state beyond these function arguments, like a `camera` struct? In c, I would just make `camera` a global variables. However, I am working in `Cython` and I want to use `glfwSetCursorPosCallback` without recourse to global variables, which are unpythonic and messy. If `camera` is a class or instance attribute, is there any way to access it from within `mouse_move` without passing it in as an argument?

Comment: This isn't really possible in Cython. I've [recommended using ctypes for similar problems in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878942/using-function-pointers-to-methods-of-classes-without-the-gil/34900829#34900829) to allow you to pass a generic Python callable but the `GLFWwindow *` window parameter makes it difficult to do that here.

Comment: There is also the possibility that `GLFWwindow` allow you to store custom data (via a void pointer, for instance) that could then be accessed from your callback. This depends on the library being used, of course. This remains quite independent from Cython.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to the general problem, but for glfw callbacks, it is possible to associate a `void*` with your `GLFWwindow` as follows:

```
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, yourVoidPtr);
```

and access it later (e.g. in a callback):

```
YourData *data = (YourData *) glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
```