# Wrong result using a PyCapsule created from a method in Cython

Tags: python, cython, pythran

We would need to create a PyCapsule from a method of a class in Cython. We managed to write a code which compiles and even runs without error but the results are wrong.

A simple example is here: https://github.com/paugier/cython_capi/tree/master/using_cpython_pycapsule_class

The capsules are executed by Pythran (one needs to use the version on github https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/pythran).

The .pyx file:

```
from cpython.pycapsule cimport PyCapsule_New


cdef int twice_func(int c):
    return 2*c


cdef class Twice:
    cdef public dict __pyx_capi__

    def __init__(self):
        self.__pyx_capi__ = self.get_capi()

    cpdef get_capi(self):
        return {
            'twice_func': PyCapsule_New(
                <void *>twice_func, 'int (int)', NULL),
            'twice_cpdef': PyCapsule_New(
                <void *>self.twice_cpdef, 'int (int)', NULL),
            'twice_cdef': PyCapsule_New(
                <void *>self.twice_cdef, 'int (int)', NULL),
            'twice_static': PyCapsule_New(
                <void *>self.twice_static, 'int (int)', NULL)}

    cpdef int twice_cpdef(self, int c):
        return 2*c

    cdef int twice_cdef(self, int c):
        return 2*c

    @staticmethod
    cdef int twice_static(int c):
        return 2*c
```

The file compiled by pythran (`call_capsule_pythran.py`).

```
# pythran export call_capsule(int(int), int)

def call_capsule(capsule, n):
    r = capsule(n)
    return r
```

Once again it is a new feature of Pythran so one needs the version on github...

And the test file:

```
try:
    import faulthandler
    faulthandler.enable()
except ImportError:
    pass

import unittest

from twice import Twice
from call_capsule_pythran import call_capsule


class TestAll(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.obj = Twice()
        self.capi = self.obj.__pyx_capi__

    def test_pythran(self):
        value = 41
        print('\n')

        for name, capsule in self.capi.items():
            print('capsule', name)
            result = call_capsule(capsule, value)

            if name.startswith('twice'):
                if result != 2*value:
                    how = 'wrong'
                else:
                    how = 'good'

                print(how, f'result ({result})\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It is buggy and gives:

```
capsule twice_func
good result (82)

capsule twice_cpdef
wrong result (4006664390)

capsule twice_cdef
wrong result (4006664390)

capsule twice_static
good result (82)
```

It shows that it works fine for the standard function and for the static function but that there is a problem for the methods.

Note that the fact that it works for two capsules seems to indicate that the problem does not come from Pythran.

### Edit

After DavidW's comments, I understand that we would have to create at run time (for example in `get_capi`) a C function with the signature `int(int)` from the bound method `twice_cdef` whose signature is actually `int(Twice, int)`.

I don't know if this is really impossible to do with Cython...

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by `call_capsule` - you say it uses Pythran but the code you've got in github (please put it here so there's a [mcve] on site...) just calls the capsule as if it were a Python object, which I really don't think should work. I'm not surprised that this is failing, but I am surprised that it works for any case.

Comment: Do I need to also copy-paste the files Makefile and setup.py here ?

Comment: Ah ok that's a bit clearer I think.

Comment: I've had a quick look. I think the basic issue is that the signature of your methods is `int(PyObject* self, int c)`. The 2 gets passed as `self` (not causing disaster since it isn't actually used...) and some arbitrary bit of memory is used as `c`. Unfortunately it isn't possible to create a C function pointer with "bound arguments" so Cython can't (and won't be able to) do it.

Comment: The only way I know to do it is to use `ctypes`/`cffi` but this is a bit messy and adds an extra layer of Python calls - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878942/using-function-pointers-to-methods-of-classes-without-the-gil/34900829#34900829 (bottom of answer). (I can probably add a real answer later when I have time if needed but hopefully the hint will be useful for now)

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this? Is it for speed? I can make something that works with `ctypes`, but it would probably be slower than just using Python callables instead of capsules+function pointers, so if you you're aiming for speed then it's a bit pointless.

Comment: We want to use Pythran to compile such file : https://bitbucket.org/fluiddyn/fluidfft/src/default/fluidfft/fft3d/dream_pythran.py . For Pythran, `ifft3d` has to be a PyCapsule pointing towards a C function (I think not using the Python interpretor). So now I don't think we are going to manage to do this this way... Anyway thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow up/expand on my comments:

The basic issue is that the Pythran is expecting a C function pointer with the signature `int f(int)` to be contained within the PyCapsule. However, the signature of your methods is `int(PyObject* self, int c)`. The `2` gets passed as `self` (not causing disaster since it isn't actually used...) and some arbitrary bit of memory is used in place of the `int c`. Unfortunately it isn't possible to use pure C code to create a C function pointer with "bound arguments" so Cython can't (and realistically won't be able to) do it.

Modification 1 is to get better compile-time type checking of what you're passing to your `PyCapsules` by creating a function that accepts the correct types and casting in there, rather than just casting to `<void*>` blindly. This doesn't solve your problem but warns you at compile-time when it isn't going to work:

```
ctypedef int(*f_ptr_type)(int)

cdef make_PyCapsule(f_ptr_type f, string):
    return PyCapsule_New(
                <void *>f, string, NULL)

# then in get_capi:
'twice_func': make_PyCapsule(twice_func, b'int (int)'), # etc
```

It is actually possible to create C function from arbitrary Python callables using `ctypes` (or `cffi`) - see [Using function pointers to methods of classes without the gil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878942/using-function-pointers-to-methods-of-classes-without-the-gil/34900829#34900829) (bottom of answer). This adds an extra layer of Python calls so isn't terribly quick, and the code is a bit messy. `ctypes` achieves this by using runtime code generation (which isn't that portable or something you can do in pure C) to build a function on the fly and then create a pointer to that.

Although you claim in the comments that you don't think you can use the Python interpreter, I don't think this is true - Pythran generates Python extension modules (so is pretty bound to the Python interpreter) and it seems to work in your test case shown here:

```
 _func_cache = []

cdef f_ptr_type py_to_fptr(f):
    import ctypes
    functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int)
    ctypes_f = functype(f)
    _func_cache.append(ctypes_f) # ensure references are kept
    return (<f_ptr_type*><size_t>ctypes.addressof(ctypes_f))[0]

# then in make_capi:
'twice_cpdef': make_PyCapsule(py_to_fptr(self.twice_cpdef), b'int (int)')
```

Unfortunately it only works for `cpdef` and not `cdef` functions since it does rely on having a Python callable. `cdef` functions can be made to work with a lambda (provided you change `get_capi` to `def` instead of `cpdef`):

```
'twice_cdef': make_PyCapsule(py_to_fptr(lambda x: self.twice_cdef(x)), b'int (int)'),
```

It's all a little messy but can be made to work.