# How to use a prange with a python function in cython?

Tags: cython

This question is closely related to: [53641278](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641278/how-to-pass-a-python-function-to-a-cython-function-that-accepts-a-function-as-a). In the comments of that question there was a suggestion by @ead to use the approach from comment by @DavidW of question [53619438](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619438/how-to-call-a-cython-cdef-function-that-contains-as-a-parameter-a-function-in#comment94105070_53619438).

In my problem, I am provided by the user with a custom python function (e.g. `times_two()`) which I don't know beforehand and I only know the data type of parameter and output (`int`and `int`). My job is to calculate this function for a big range of parameters (e.g. `1000`). To speed up, I'd like to use `prange` which requires `C` data types.

I want to use the approach from the mentioned comment and I try this:

script.pyx

```
import ctypes

ctypedef int (* FuncPtr) (int tt)
ftype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)

cdef loop_over(FuncPtr cy_f_ptr):
    cdef:
        int i, s = 0

    for i in range(1000):
        s += cy_f_ptr(i)

    return s

cpdef get_sum(func):
    cdef FuncPtr cy_f_ptr = (<FuncPtr *> <size_t> ctypes.addressof(ftype(func)))[0]
    s = loop_over(cy_f_ptr)
    return s
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name="script", ext_modules=cythonize("script.pyx", compiler_directives={"language_level": "3"}))
```

terminal

```
python setup.py build_ext -i
```

main.py

```
from script import get_sum


def times_two(x):
    return x*2


print(get_sum(times_two))
```

When running, I get the following error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

My expectation was that the code will print the value `999000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your code is crashing because you've thrown away a temporary:

You've changed

```
f = ftype(func)
cdef FuncPtr cy_f_ptr = (<FuncPtr *> <size_t> ctypes.addressof(f))[0]
```

to

```
cdef FuncPtr cy_f_ptr = (<FuncPtr *> <size_t> ctypes.addressof(ftype(func)))[0]
```

The `ftype` object must be kept alive for as long as the function pointer is. In my version it is, while in your version the `ftype` object is destroyed pretty much instantly, meaning the function pointer is invalid as soon as you have it.

---

However, there's a fundamental problem here: to call a Python function you MUST hold the GIL, which means you can't use `prange` to parallelize it. Your function pointer scheme disguises this a little but it's still true.

What would sort of work is if you introduce a `with gil:` round the call of `cy_f_ptr`. This would only be worthwhile if the function releases the GIL internally (i.e. ends up calling into optimized C code itself). It's possible that `ctypes` gets the GIL itself - I'm not sure - but this still wouldn't change the calculation that you can't parallelize Python code like this.

Comment: Yes, changing to `f = ftype(func)` did work and printed the expected result.

And also thanks for the second commet, I did want to  "trick" cython but good to know it won't work.